# What's the minimum thickness of side window glass in the US?

Tags: car, door, power-windows, window

For cars made in 2017, what's the minimum thickness of side window glass in the US?  Or *is* there any minimum thickness?

---

Origin of question:  A power window plastic sash connector sold as a correct fit for a 15 year old car with *5mm* windows, turned out to be *4mm* -- might have been a vendor error, or product degradation, since some plastics can [shrink with age](http://www.materials.ac.uk/events/doc/plastics-leeson-aging.doc) during storage.  The product copy for the sash connector didn't seem to include any measurement of what size glass it fit, or data on whether a *4mm* sash might actually fit some other car.    Which raised the question of how thick current side window glass actually is.

Comment: It may be covered under the [National Highway Traffic Safety Administration's](https://www.nhtsa.gov/sites/nhtsa.dot.gov/files/fmvss-quickrefguide-hs811439.pdf) Federal Motor Vehicle Safety Standards and Regulations, Standard No. 205: Glazing Materials, but I can only find a brief summary of what it's about, not the entire standard.